# Are step sizes in quadratic programming solvers analytically exact?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

In [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d198/4defd4ccd17ff944219ebd34420e3fb78239.pdf) ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02591962)), Goldfarb and Idnani describe an algorithm for solving a certain subset of quadratic programs. This algorithm (or a very similar one) is implemented in the [quadprogpp](https://github.com/fnoorian/quadprogpp) package for R. On page 29 of their paper, they show a few possible solution paths leading to a point of optimality given three inequality constraints. It appears that the solver steps *exactly* onto that solution. This seems to contrast with gradient-based solvers, which have a specified tolerance and a (potentially dynamic) step size and iterate toward a solution, but often converge to a point that is suboptimal but satisfies said tolerance metric.

My questions are the following:

1. Does the quadratic solver described in the paper (and implemented in the package) actually find the exact solution (subject to numerical imprecision, of course), or is it just getting to a solution that's within some tolerance of the true optimum?
2. If the answer to the first question is the latter (inexact solution, within tolerance of true optimum), how would I go about adjusting the tolerance and/or step size so as to make the search more granular? I understand that this may be slightly off-topic since it crosses into software/programming, but any suggestions would be much appreciated.
3. If the answer to the first question is the latter, what is the stopping criterion, and how can it be adjusted?

Comment: Please link to the paper using the DOI and then include another link to the freely available PDF. Your question would age much better that way.

Comment: I had never heard of DOI until you mentioned it. Apparently it stands for "Digital Object Identifier." But I have no idea how to find a paper's DOI number or generate a link based on it. Further guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The DOI is [this one](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02591962). You can find it at the bottom of the [Springer page](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02591962).

Comment: Thanks, good info. Any thoughts/insight on the question itself?